# Monaco-editor performance

Tags: monaco-editor

I have a performance issue with Monaco Editor even when I specify which language it should use. Is there some way to optimize the loading speed and make it as lightweight as possible? Otherwise what else can be done to decrease the loading time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very vague description. Can you go into more detail what you do that make Monaco apparently slow to load?

Comment: Nothing specific I just parse value to it and when I want to display it. It takes ages to load.

Comment: How large is the data? What type of data is it actually (large JSON or so)? Try disabling all features in Monaco (e.g. soft wrapping and folding are pretty slow on large documents).

Comment: Yes, it is mostly JSON and it can be up to 200 lines that are being shown. The issue is that I haven't found in documentation what I could disable to increase the speed or how it should be disabled